# How to find a string pattern and modify it in PHP?

Tags: php, string, replace

I want to convert substrings of a string in the form of `#123` to `<a href='show.php?id=123'>#123</a>`.
So make them links.

So the string `"take a look at #42"` transforms into `"take a look at <a href='show.php?id=42'>#42</a>"`.

Does php have a built-in function for that?

Thanks

Comment: This is basically answered so I'll just post as a comment: http://3v4l.org/Y65uW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/([^#]+)(#[\d]+)([^#]+)/';
$str = 'Take a look at #42';
if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)){
    echo $matches[1]."<a href='show.php?id=".substr($matches[2], 1)."'>". $matches[2].'</a>'.$matches[3];
}
```

This outputs:

```
Take a look at <a href="show.php?id=42">#42</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't match the pattern. Should i change [a-z] to [0-9]?

Comment: and when I changed it to 0-9 , it found the pattern, but removed the other parts. so "look at #42" become "<a href='show.php?id=42'>42</a>"

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string="take a look at #42";
if (preg_match('/#[0-9]+/', $string, $matches)){
echo "<a href='show.php?id=".substr($matches[0], 1)."'>". substr($matches[0], 1).'</a>';

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to perform the replacement:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/#(\w+)/', function($match) {
    return sprintf('<a href="show.php?id=%s">%s</a>',
        $match[1],
        '#' . $match[1]
    );
}, 'take a look at #42');
// look at <a href="show.php?id=42">#42</a>
```

While not strictly required here, make sure you escape your HTML properly otherwise :)

See also: [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)